# Comenzar en 1 array en php

Tags: php, array

¿Como podria hacer para comenzar con la key en 1 del array?
Necesito reemplazar el cero por el uno..

```
        array(13) { [0]=> string(1) "2" 
    [1]=> string(1) "3" 
    [2]=> string(11) "comentarios" 
    [3]=> string(13) "alfred"

//Objetivo
        array(13) { [1]=> string(1) "2" 
    [2]=> string(1) "3" 
    [3]=> string(11) "comentarios" 
    [4]=> string(13) "alfred"
```

Comment: Como llenas el array?

Comment: con valores `$arr = $valor` `array_push($arr,$valor1,$valor2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes dejar el primer hueco ocupado con `null` y posteriormente desecharlo mediante `unset()`

```
array_push($arr, null, "2", "3", "comentarios", "alfred");
unset($arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza array_unshift para agregar un elemento al inicio del array y luego lo borras.

```
$numeros = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'];
array_unshift($numeros, 'este_lo_borrare');
unset($numeros[0]);
```